# Building an exe for a python script that uses Maya modules (Py2exe)

Tags: python, dll, py2exe, maya

I know this is a long shot but I'm hoping someone on here has any experience with this as I can't find anything mentioning it online. I have a python script that imports modules from Autodesk Maya. This python script is run through mayapy.exe instead of python.exe which is whats throwing me off. I would rather not have to include a bat file with my script and have the users set the location of mayapy.exe in order to use it. I would prefer to somehow package mayapy.exe with my script using something like py2exe. I'm a little lost on where to go from here honestly.

If I run py2exe normally on my script, its result gives me the error cannot find maya.cmds, as expected. Is there a way I can find the dll to include? I tried running Dependency walker on mayapy.exe but I'm venturing into new territory here. There were only 2 dll's used from the Maya install directory base.dll and python26.dll, the rest were all system dlls. If anyone has tried any of this please share or if anyone has any advice or path I can look down or a website I can go to I would be very grateful. Thanks so much!

P.s. In case it helps at all, this is the python script imports:

```
try:
    import maya.standalone
    maya.standalone.initialize()
except:
    pass
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
from time import time as tTime
from glob import iglob
from shutil import copy
from os.path import join
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

The point of the script is to create a maya file, do some things in it, then save it. Using the maya interpreter(mayapy.exe) it does this without ever opening maya, which is what I was wanting.

Comment: If you could include the dll, its still dependent on all Maya binaries. Even so it starts Maya but without showing a Maya GUI(that's what the initialize does). This dependency would manifest as a need to know where Maya is located on disk bringing you back to the batch issue. However you can do this just that your installer need to find Maya and write the info for the exe to read. The bigger problem is probably that you can not rely on the external dependencies of PyQT working even if you'd use py2EXE. And you would need possibly need a commercial version of PyQT4.

Comment: not sure if it's going to be much use, but I suspect this isn't possible (or not without a heap of work..). Just did some poking around with maya.cmds which is a bare  __init__.py file, and so the maya.cmds is populated via the call to maya.standalone.initialize() which references the standalone.pyd file in that directory. I don't know exactly *what's* going on though... For what it's worth however, if you go to the /bin directory where mayapy.exe lives, you'll find a commandList file which maps out the command to the relevant .dll. @joojaa also points out the other issue you'll hit..

Comment: and oops, forgot to mention, commands.py in \Python\lib\site-packages\maya\app which is the way in which that file is x-reffed and used I believe. I sorta stopped playing around at this point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure what I wanted to do was not possible. Instead I split my program into two parts, one requiring Maya one not, for the part requiring Maya I just had it do a registry lookup for the Maya install location and used that. If it were possibly to include the necessary files for my script, I'm sure Autodesk would not have approved in the first place anyways.